# How do I use doctype and html tags in a react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bun

I'm trying to do SSR with Bun and I want to have a `Layout` component that I use as a base for my pages.

Here is my Index page component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

export const render = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>index</h1>
      <p>the count is {count}</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Here is my `Layout` component:

```
import type { ReactNode } from "react"

export default (props: { children : ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet">
                </head>
                <body>
                    {props.children}
                </body>
            </html>
        </>
    )
}
```

When I run the server and try and visit the page, I get the following error:

**BuildError**: Expected identifier but found "!"
In app/components/Layout.tsx:6:14

```
            <!doctype html>
```

**BuildError**: Expected ">" but found ""
In app/components/Layout.tsx:6:15

```
            <!doctype html>
```

**BuildError**: Syntax Error!!
In app/components/Layout.tsx:19:12

```
        </>
```

VSCode also gives me this linting error:

> JSX fragment has no corresponding closing tag.

How can I have `doctype` and `html` tags in my `Layout` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `renderToReadableStream` will auto-add the doctype to the component, so I can just use my original example without the `doctype` tag and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to `index.html` please find below stackblitz where we have it inside the `public` folder, you can render the rest inside the body tag!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div> <!-- render react code here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pqjs8l?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2Findex.tsx,public%2Findex.html&title=React%20Starter)